# Facebook 'like button' on page with dynamic content(ajax)

Tags: ajax, facebook-like

Usually the facebook 'like button' deactivates once a user clicks on it once. However, let's say I have a page that loads dynamic content (e.g. a picture viewer), and I want the user to be able to like one images (images my be accessed through their own link via generated url), but then move on to like another one as well, without having the button deactivating after being clicked once. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the JS SDK you should destroy the existing button and create another one, but the like button links to a specific URL so you'd have to make sure you were liking a different URL for each image.

[Why is my Facebook Like button broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311721/why-is-my-facebook-like-button-broken/) talks about making dynamic like buttons.